# Как установить скидки и лимиты закупок?

Tags: php, magento

Мне нужно установить цены на услуги на платформе Magento.
Есть ряд условий: например, человек должен выбрать количество товаров, в зависимости от этой цифры будет рассчитан процент скидки; кроме того, есть ограничение на количество выбранных товаров, - если больше двухсот, то пользователь должен увидеть сообщение на экране "Contact us".

Я так понимаю, платформа имеет стандартные методы установки цены. Как их можно изменить? Или указанное возможно реализовать стандартными средствами Magento?

Comment: Не совсем понятно про какие камеры идет речь и как это связано с услугой и т.д. Но в общем виде надо смотреть в сторону custom товаров. Когда есть базовый товар (в вашем случае услуга), а для него можно выбирать параметры.

Answer (score 1):

Про скидки: в Magento есть такая функция, как `tier price`. Выставляется количество, свыше которого цена изменяется, можно выставить несколько пороговых значений. На странице товара в админке во вкладке находится цена.
По поводу максимального количества: посмотри в `system->config->checkout`, там что-то вроде `min cart qty / max cart qty`. `Min cart qty` там точно есть. Может быть, и максимум. Сообщение «свяжитесь с нами» при достижении максимума можно доставить в шаблоне `/app/design/твоя_тема/template/catalog/product/add_to_cart.phtml`.